# Como imprimir em html em forma de cupon fiscal?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como poderia imprir na tela html a tabela abaixo em forma de cupon fiscal ?
Tipo o da imagem seguinte .
do lado da refeição a quantidade.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para que possamos te ajudar é necessário que você poste o código do que você já fez até aqui. Só olhando as imagens não tem muito o fazer

Comment: Se você já conseguiu montar o cupom bonitinho, basta imprimir. <button onclick="window.print()">Imprimir</button>